# Magick.NET is unable to read Exif tags

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, imagemagick, exif

I'm trying to use [this example](http://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exif%20data&referringTitle=Documentation) of **Magick.NET** library to read Exif information from an Image, but at the moment that I try to iterate the Exif values I get an unhandled error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Magick.NET-AnyCPU.dll
>
> Additional information: La matriz de origen no es suficientemente
>   larga. Compruebe srcIndex, la longitud y los límites inferiores de la
>   matriz.
>
> (In English: The source Array is not long enough. Check srcIndex,
>   length and lower bounds of the array)

This is the code that I'm using:

```
    Using img As New MagickImage("C:\Jpeg With Exif.jpg")

        ' Retrieve the Exif Information (if any)
        Dim ExifData As ExifProfile = img.GetExifProfile()

        ' This instruction throws the same unhandled exception that the 'For' below.
        ' MsgBox(ExifData.Values.Count) 

        Select Case ExifData Is Nothing

            Case True ' Zero Exif values found.
                MessageBox.Show("The image does not contains Exif information", "Image Information",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            Case Else ' At least 1 Exif value found.

                ' StringBuilder to format the Exif entries.
                Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

                ' Iterate the Exif values.
                For Each Value As ExifValue In ExifData.Values

                ' ******
                ' Here throws the unhandled exception.
                ' Even if the For block is empty of instructions.
                ' ******

                    With sb
                        .AppendLine(String.Format("{0}({1}): {2}",
                                                  Value.Tag,
                                                  Value.DataType,
                                                  Value.ToString()))
                    End With '/ sb

                Next Value

                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString, "Exif Image Information",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End Select '/ ExifData Is Nothing

    End Using '/ img As New MagickImage
```

Then this is a bug, or I'm doing something wrong?

**Note:** I previously added Exif information with the [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) program using this command:

```
.\exiftool.exe -artist="value" "c:\Test.jpg"
```

Here is the image that I've tried to examine:
http://www.mediafire.com/?42kvy8hhu4mgpz7

Comment: Are you using the latest version? And can you post a link to your image file?

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version, it's my first time using this library, and I need to say that I'm facing the same unhandled exception with the other example that learns how to create a thumbnail of the Exif, the image that I'm using can be downloaded here: http://i.imgur.com/mG0IA6R.jpg (it contains an 'Author' and 'Copyright' exif values), thanks for comment!

Comment: You could ask question related to Magick.NET here also next time: magick.codeplex.com/discussions. It's easier then asking questions in the comments. Can you post the image on something like dropbox? imgur seems to strip metadata.

Comment: @dlemstra here is the proper image: http://www.mediafire.com/?42kvy8hhu4mgpz7 PS: I appreciatte your suggestion but I never had good luck obtaining help in codeplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered a bug in Magick.NET. Your image contains invalid sizes that where not correctly checked. This will be fixed in Magick.NET 6.8.9.401.

As also pointed out in the comments you can also report problems / ask questions here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions. I will reply to all questions asked there.

With a build that includes a fix for this problem I was able to extract the following values:

```
XResolution: 1
YResolution: 1
ResolutionUnit: 1
Artist: Phil Harvey
YCbCrPositioning: 1
Copyright: 2011 Phil Harvey
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not noted that you are the developer of Magick.Net! so if you suggest me to post my problems there to obtain your support then ofc the next time i will do it, thanks for your time! PS: I would like to suggest you to create a new example for the codeplex documentation of course only if you want to, an example about reordering frames in a gif, I'm very curious about that!